# Editing code from webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a system where I can edit my elements(navbar,paragraph,image etc) from web-page and I know that its possible with java script but how would I change my code permanently from web-page because when I reloading my page all of customizes are vanishing and becoming to default form.

I need this because I am creating a website and this is really tough for me to do it alone so that I am taking help from my friends by no one of them know HTML well. So that I'm trying to making a system so that they could update the page by the interface created by me.

Basically I want to know that how would I change my HTML/CSS code permanently from web-page.

Comment: Do you mean using the browser's dev tools?

Comment: You need a CMS...

Comment: not even sure if this is a real question

Comment: this is what angularJS is all about.

Comment: Its like posting blog in a website by user but I have to do it in offline then upload it. I can changing or creating elements with javascripts HTML DOM. But I cant making the permanent change of it. #Clive

Comment: I don't see a way to achieve this without server side coding, because the files that are hosted should be changed from remote machines. A simpler approach, you should something like Git, GitHub, PythonAnywhere, etc.. where you can all edit the website.

Comment: Thanks #mplungjan #anuja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a server side scripting language such as PHP or ASP.NET. This will grant you access to local files. What you have to do next is store the variable content in a database, or, if the content is too large (long paragraphs for example), you can store them in an xml file.